# Apache Server with PHP 7.1 has wrong encoding settings. strftime and strtotime return wrong format

Tags: php, apache, encoding, utf-8, localization

I am a bit confused why the standard server settings here are giving back the wrong encoding format. On my local machine everything works fine: An CMS backend displays the current month as a string in German and for 03 (March) it returns 'Mär'.

On the server it returns "M�r" back. I know that this is caused while output ISO format in UTF-8, without encoding it (utf8_encode).

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL,"de_DE");

echo var_dump((strftime('%b', strtotime('2007-03-01'))));

// Output -> string(3) "M�r"
```

How to change the server settings, that PHP uses UTF-8 and not the ISO format for dates? I cannot use utf8_encode function because it's the CMS which uses PHP strftime and strtotime function.

the default server php.ini already include `default_charset = 'UTF-8'`
in my htaccess I included `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`

Comment: Sounds like you need to raise a bug for the CMS you're using

Comment: It's working perfectly locally so I assume I have the wrong PHP, apache settings, don't you think ? The output here is just a blank page which has nothing todo with the CMS.

Comment: Check [this comment in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php#72482)

Comment: OK. So its maybe really a bug in the CMS.

Comment: Try comparing output of `setlocale(LC_ALL,"de_DE");` with setlocale(LC_ALL,"de_DE.UTF-8");` in the server and see if it resolves the issue, and if it does then make a request from the CMS developers to prefer .UTF-8 locales if there are multiple ones available.

Comment: Got it ! it was de_DE.utf8 . I prepared a nice answer, if somebody else runs into this error. But I think it's your reputation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @apokryfos who sent me to the right direction. Like [in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php#72482) mentioned the function strftime() use the locales installed in your system (linux).

> ...the result will use the iso-8859-1 charset even if you have all your system, files and configuration options in UTF-8...

In the config of my CMS a had to revert that line:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');
```

to explicitly use UTF-8 version

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8');
```